# Fill a feedback form with drop down choices and submit it

Tags: python, forms, automation

I want to automate the task of filling a feedback form.

The form looks like this
[image: Feedback Form]

There are 15 columns and 11 rows in the form. and each answer has 5 choices to choose from a drop down menu.

I am not able to understand which library could help me in python to accomplish this task.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: If this is an online form, you can use selenium

Comment: @Aritesh is right, the best package to use is Selenium. It's a webdriver that can _click_ and interact with the site.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

(leaving a link to help you out with the python docs)

Comment: @Aritesh Yes, it is an online form.

Comment: @SmokeyBaxter let me check it out. I hope I can also login via Selenium.

Comment: @shardul08 I posted an answer so I could explain Selenium a little more than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an answer because I'd like to show you how to use Selenium's features.

Import the package like this

`from selenium import webdriver`

You can initialize the driver as such (I'm using the chromedriver):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.environ['FILE_PATH'])
```

Here I pass it the chromedriver filepath. [Here is the download link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Logging in can work like this, where you find the element you want to enter input into (I'm using `find_element_by_id` but you can use other means) and then pass it a value. Then I submit the form using `.click()` on the button element.

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')

username.send_keys(os.environ['USERNAME'])
password.send_keys(os.environ['PASSWORD'])

driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-submit').click()
```